# Obtain the set of real numbers $c$ such that $\frac{\log_2x}{x}=c.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Question: Obtain the set of real numbers $c$ such that $$\frac{\log_2x}{x}=c$$ has only one real solution.

My approach: Firstly observe that for some $x>0$,  $$\frac{\log_2x}{x}=c\iff \log_2x=xc\iff \log_2x-xc=0.$$

Now let $f(x):=\log_2x-xc, \forall x>0.$ Now clearly $f$ is differentiable $\forall x>0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln2}-c, \forall x>0.$

Now $$f'(x)=0\iff \frac{1}{x\ln2}-c=0\iff x=\frac{1}{c\ln 2}.$$ We know that $x>0$, thus we must have $\frac{1}{c\ln 2}>0\iff c>0.$ Thus $\forall c>0$, $f'(x)=0$ iff $x=\frac{1}{c\ln 2}$.

Now $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2\ln2}.$ Thus $f''(x)>0, \forall x>0$ and $\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f''\left(\frac{1}{c\ln2}\right)<0, \forall c>0.$

Observe that $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=-\infty, \forall c\in\mathbb{R}.$

Also $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\log_2x-xc)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\left(\frac{\log_2x}{x}-c\right)=-\infty, \forall c>0.$

Thus $f\left(\frac{1}{c\ln 2}\right)$ is the maximum value of $f(x), \forall c>0$. From here, we can also conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing on the interval $\left(0,\frac{1}{c\ln 2}\right]$ and strictly decreasing on the interval $\left[\frac{1}{c\ln 2}, +\infty\right)$.

Thus $f$ has exactly one root for that $c>0,$ whose maximum value is $0$. Let us find that $c$.
$$f\left(\frac{1}{c\ln 2}\right)=0\iff c=\frac{2^{-1/\ln 2}}{\ln 2}=\frac{1}{e\ln 2}.$$

Now when $c<0$, we have $f'(x)>0, \forall x>0.$ Thus $\forall c<0$, $f$ is a strictly increasing function.

Also observe that $\forall c<0$, $f(1)=-c>0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=-\infty.$ Thus by IVT (since, $f$ is continuous), we can conclude that when $c<0$, $f$ has exactly one root.

Now when $c=0$, $$f(x)=0\iff \log_2x=0\iff x=1.$$ Thus when $c=0$, $f$ has exactly one root.

Thus the required set of real numbers $c$ is $$S:=(-\infty,0]\cup\left\{\frac{1}{e\ln 2}\right\}.$$

Can someone check if my solution is completely correct or not? And a better and shorter solution will be appreciated.

Comment: It is incorrect. The image of $x\mapsto \frac{\ln(x)}x$ for $x\in]0,\infty]$ is $$]-\infty,1/e]$$ If you take $\log_2$ then you need to divide by $\ln(2)$. Have a look at this plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln%28x%29%2Fx%20from%200%20to%205

Comment: The question doesn’t make sense. Is $x$ fixed? Is the equation supposed to be satisfied by all $x$ (impossible)?  Some $x$? Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x},$$ which is only a positive constant multiple of yours, and so essentially equivalent to it with respect to this problem, is increasing for $0<x<e$ and decreasing for $x>e$ since the derivative is $$\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}.$$  Since $f(x)<0$ for $x<1,$ it follows that there is a local maximum at $x=e.$ Thus the function is concave for all $x>0.$ Hence *the equation $f(x)=c$ has at most two solutions for each $c\le f(e)=1/e.$*

*PS.* For more exact analysis, note that as $x\to+\infty,$ we have that $f(x)\to 0^+$ and as $x\to +0,$ we have that the limit is $-\infty.$ Thus we have that precisely two solutions exist for all $c$ satisfying $0<c<1/e$ and when $c=1/e$ or $c\le 0,$ we have just one solution to $f(x)=c.$

Comment: I guess, $c$ will be equal to $\frac{1}{e\ln 2}$ and not $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @SanketBiswas If you read the first sentence again, you should notice that I used the base $e$ for simplicity. You could easily adapt it to your particular problem.